# Python multiprocessing with tuples is not working

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying out multiprocessing in Python 3 and I have run into some odd behaviour (well, at least it is odd to me!).

Essentially, I create a list of 10 random numbers. I then loop over a range (in my example, it is 2) and for each iteration, I use `pool.apply_async` to process the random numbers in parallel. The results of the "processing" are stored in a list so that when all processing is complete, I can print my results. I expect to see 2*10 results.

What I find, however, is that for some reason, I see just 2 results (i.e the 2 iterations in my first loop):

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import random

class Calculator:

    def calculate(self, links):
        print("LENGHT:", len(links)) # 48
        tups=[]
        for datasetlink in links:
            print(datasetlink)
            tups.append("GO", datasetlink)
        return tups

dslinks = random.sample(range(1, 101), 10)
result_list = []

def Process(datasetlinks):

    calc = Calculator();
    tups = calc.calculate(datasetlinks)
    return tups;

def log_result(result):
    result_list.append(result)

def apply_async_with_callback():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    for i in range(2):
        pool.apply_async(Process, args = (dslinks,), callback = log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    DoPrintResults()

def DoPrintResults():
    for result in result_list:
        print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    apply_async_with_callback()
    end = time.time()
    print("Execution took: ", (end-start), " seconds")
```

If I remove the `tups=[]`, `tups.append("GO", datasetlink)` and `return tups` from the `Calculator.calculate` function, everything works as expected and I see that the `for-loop` of `Calculator.calculate` is hit 20 times.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you make tups into tuples. It currently seems to be alist

Comment: Are you not getting a `TypeError` at `tups.append("GO", datasetlink)`? `append` only takes one argument.

Comment: @Professor_Joykill OMG. Thank you. It was not giving me any error as wilusdaman had asked and therefore I completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
tups.append("GO", datasetlink)
```

Change that to:

```
tups.append(datasetlink)
```

Debugging multiprocess code can be tricky. One way of debugging it is using exceptions. Put everything in `Process` in a `try` block:

```
def Process(datasetlinks):
    try:
        calc = Calculator();
        tups = calc.calculate(datasetlinks)
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])
    return tups;
```

That gave me `<type 'exceptions.NameError'>` and when I moved the try block to calculate:

```
def calculate(self, links):
    try:
        print("LENGHT:", len(links)) # 48                                                                      
        tups=[]
        for datasetlink in links:
            print(datasetlink)
            tups.append("GO", datasetlink)
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])
    return tups
```

I instead got `<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>`

Comment: Thanks. This is what @Professor_Joykill  had pointed out and so I was able to rectify my issue. The try/catch is a good idea, too. It was throwing me as I did not get any errors.